# Как применить rewarded video admob более чем в одной activity

Tags: android, видео, admob

Как применить rewarded video в андроид в двух разных активити, независимых одна от другой (разные мини игры)? Включая необходимость применения children tag. 
Правильно ли, чтобы была только одна дна инициализация MobileAds.initialize в запуске первой активити?
А request? Один static request, до инициализации? Ведь необходимо использовать таг до инициализации.. 
И как поступить  с загрузкой следущего видео сразу после просмотра? Ведь если этого не сделать, каждый раз приходится долго ждать, а если сделать лоадинг , а игрок перейдет в другую активити, то видео останется неиспользованным и видимо, это дает сбой. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1) Да, `MobileAds.initialize()` должен быть вызван один раз для всего приложения.

2) Если под request вы понимаете создание класса AdRequest, тогда да, его можно переиспользовать на несколько рекламных View. Это просто "контейнер" для хранения ваших конфигураций. Создавать после инициализации, не понял, что имеется в виду под "нужно использовать тэг до инициализации". AdRequest не нужен на инициализации вообще, он нужен уже для загрузки рекламы.

3) Думаю дать сбой не должно, вы проверяли? Но если вдруг дает, то решение простое - обнулить `RewardedVideoAd`, созданный в прошлой активити, а затем создать заново в данной активити с новым контекстом и уже через новый `RewardedVideoAd` грузить рекламу.